# How do I do admin inlines in Django 1.0?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am working through the examples in a Django book that I have, but the book was written for 0.96 and I am using 1.0.2, yeah, I know, not the best idea. But reading Django's "porting your apps from 0.96 to 1.0" doc has cleared up most of the differences for me. Until I get to the point where I need to implement inline editing of a second model on the admin page.

I am using a custom keyword search model to allow you to search pages made using Django's Flatpages app. Below is the model:

`class SearchKeyword(models.Model):`

```
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    page = models.ForeignKey(FlatPage)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.keyword
```

What should my admin.py look like to set up a StackedInline for SearchKeyword that shows up on the Flatpages admin page?

Comment: I would realy, really, like to stress how awesome the django docs are. You should just read them and drop the outdated book.

Comment: ...and read the upcoming 2nd edition of the book while it's being written. Available on-line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class SearchKeywordInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SearchKeyword
    extra = 3

class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [SearchKeywordInline]

# unregister the FlatPage model from the admin site so I can
# register it again with the inline stuff (Thanks Carl & Jason)
admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, FlatPageAdmin)
```

More info in the official [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#ref-contrib-admin)

**Update**: Fixed the code to suit your requirements.

Comment: hrm, that is basically what I had and it wasn't working, still not working after I copied your code. Guess there is something else wrong...

Comment: With the above code (once you fix FlatpageAdmin to FlatPageAdmin) I would guess you would get an AlreadyRegistered error; you may need to admin.site.unregister(FlatPage) first.  And you may also want to inherit your FlatPageAdmin from the one in contrib/flatpages/admin.py

Comment: I did briefly see an AlreadyRegistered error, but it went away when I refreshed the page. I'll try out the unregister bit, thanks.

Comment: Fixed the Flatpage/FlatPage typo.

Comment: using the admin.site.unregister(Flatpage) that Carl suggested fixed me right up.

Answer (score 0):

Check out 
[link text](http://blog.haydon.id.au/2008/08/2-your-first-django-site-simple-cms.html)
I think that will hit the spot

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code once I got it working correctly. Thanks for the help guys

```
from cms.search.models import SearchKeyword
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.contrib import admin

class SearchKeywordInline(admin.StackedInline):

    model = SearchKeyword
    extra = 3

class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = [SearchKeywordInline]


# unregister the FlatPage model from the admin site so I can
# register it again with the inline stuff.
admin.site.unregister(FlatPage)
admin.site.register(FlatPage, FlatPageAdmin)
```